# How to check condition at THEN clause of CASE statement in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement like need to check condition in THEN clause of `CASE` statement.  Please find below the example

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable t
WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN (t.producttypeid = 1)
        THEN (CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.releasedate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.createddate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME)) 
    WHEN (t.producttypeid IN (2, 3))
        THEN (CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.createddate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.releasedate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME))
    END
```

Explanation of the above query : In the where clause of the above query I used case statement for checking producttypeid and based on the value of producttypeid I have to check dates of releasedate and createddate.

But above query will give below syntax errors :

> *Incorrect syntax near '>'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.*

I have achieved the above task by using two select statement and separate where clause with union. Please find below query

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable t
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.releasedate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.createddate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME)) 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable t
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.createddate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.releasedate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME))
```

So The dates checking should be done in THEN clause based on CASE statement.

But I want to achieve this above task with single select query.  Please help me with this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What datatype are you using to store `releasedate` and `createddate`?  I'm a bit confused by the double conversion, first to a date and then to a string.

Comment: I am using DateTime datatype.  double conversion is required to check only date comparision.  I am not considering time.

Comment: Got it!  You can simplify like so: `... CAST(DateTimeField_1 AS DATE) = CAST(DateTimeField_2 AS DATE)...`.  Should be easier to read and quicker to type.  If @fafl helped you please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working solution.

Comment: you are right but i am using sqlserver ce.  In CE DATE function not supported.

Comment: Vijay - I did not know that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with some boolean algebra. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable t WHERE t.producttypeid IN (1, 2, 3) AND ((
    t.producttypeid = 1 AND (
        CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.releasedate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.createddate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME)
    )
) OR (
    t.producttypeid IN (2, 3) AND (
        CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.createddate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(t.releasedate AS DATETIME), 111) AS DATETIME)
    )
))
```

Comment: This is fine.  But i have to check producttypeid condition also.

Comment: like first i have to check t.producttypeid in (1,2,3) and after that i have to check these dates condition.  because there are 5 types of product type ids but i need to consider only 1,2 and 3 only.

Comment: Ok i added an extra check in the beginning. But it should produce the same results.